# Implement a generic search on persisted JPA entities

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, lucene, jpql

Say we have an entity `Foo` that contains various data fields, one being a `List<Bar>`.  In turn, a Bar has various data fields, one being a `List<Snafu>`.  We want to give the user an input field that will allow them to do a generic search on persisted Foo records.  For example, they search for `test` and a Foo record will be found that has a Bar that has a Snafu with a data field containing the string "test".

Is it possible to do this kind of search efficiently, or will a different technology be required (e.g. Lucene)?

Comment: Can you provide a more formal definition of *generic* search? The example you given only suggests table joins (`Foo` -> `Bar` -> `Snafu`).

Comment: So how would you search all data fields in Foo, Bar, and Snafu for a term "test"?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/070b3b/2 - just rough idea. But my point is that you should define first what you want. Searching in DB is quite different from searching in Lucene.

Comment: But what if you have two other varchar fields, y and z, that also need to be included in the search?

Comment: Then you write relevant SQL for that. Hint: I am not arguing against Lucene, the only I ask for you is to define what *generic* means. You could as well denormalize your data (say, create a view) and achieve the same result. And it's not like you don't know your database structure when running SQL.

Comment: Sure!  By _generic_ I mean being able to type a search term and find records for which that search term matches for any field.  It may be the description, the name, the date, etc.  What I was most concerned about is the efficiency and scalability of writing such a query, especially with my limited SQL and JPQL knowledge.  To be honest, I would prefer not to have to use Lucene.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you should look at using lucene.

The hibernate-search library (powered by lucene) is pretty simple to get up and running on your entities with annotations and fits quite simply with hibernate projects.

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is enough for you just to find out the reference to `Foo`, you could create a database view containing records from all the referenced tables. Writing SQL for such a view would be really simple.

Otherwise you can look at Lucene (like rhinds pointed out) but this means you will have to replicate your database data elsewhere. On the other hand, the search would be much more powerful (e.g. Lucene, unlike DB, can easily handle misspellings).